# Remote-debug in recent opera versions

Tags: opera, remote-debugging, opera-mobile

Remote debugging was easily possible with Opera Dragonfly in much previous versions of Opera. But Dragonfly has been replaced with Chromium based developer tools in recent versions and the remote debugging tool can not be found there .

So what is the way to do the remote-debugging in Opera (i.e. version 30 ) while using [Opera Mobile Classic Emulator](http://www.opera.com/developer/mobile-emulator) in desktop ?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the Emulator.

- Open the site in Opera and then the developer tools (such as "right klick" -> "inspect element").
- the second button from the left: "toggle device mode"
- chose a device and reload the page
- you can work with all the dev tools on the emulated page!

If neccessary you can add custom devices in Settings -> Devices

Have fun!

Comment: I see, let me check more.

Comment: Actually web based simulators do not work as real devices and wrong results do come out of those. So if we want to test using  a real device, we need a way to debug it remotely. How to do the remote-debug  in Opera?